# Replace escape forward slash in NSULRL query item

Tags: ios, objective-c

How do I escape a query item in NSUrl without getting "%252F" instead of "%2F"?

```
NSString value = "an/example";
NSString* encodedMimeType = [value stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters: [NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]];
NSArray<NSURLQueryItem *> *queryItems = @[
  [[NSURLQueryItem alloc] initWithName:@"param1" value:encodedValue],
];
NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents new];
components.scheme = @"https";
components.host = @"www.example.com";
components.path = @"/path";
components.queryItems = queryItems;
NSLog(@"%@", [components URL].absoluteString];
```

This appears to give me a 252 instead of 2 in the string...

Comment: Just pass not encoded value, `NSURLComponents` will encode them for you.

Comment: `%` is transformed into `%25` if you percent encode it. So you encode yourself the `/` which will be `%2F`, and the the `NSURLQueryItem` logic will encode `%2F`, but since `2F` is legal as such, it will transform only the `%` outputting the result. So why double encoding? Remove yours, no?

Comment: When I use url.absoluteString, it is not encoded, and i need to use the string...